# With Python Black (prior to 19.2b), how to skip normalizing underscores in numeric literals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-black

I am using Black with Python 3.7 (in VS Code).

When I format my code, the numeric literals are normalized with the underscore (e.g. `1562202` => `1_562_202`).

How to use Black Formatting without formatting by using the underscore?

**NOTE**
From black version [19.2b](https://github.com/ambv/black#192b0), this question becomes obsolete.

Comment: Is `1_562_202` a string or something?

Comment: @U9-Forward No, it's a numeric literal allowed in Python 3.7.

Comment: Numeric underscore normalization was removed in [black 19.2b0](https://github.com/ambv/black#192b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the official documentation of **Black**, the following option can skip adding underscore in numeric literals:

> -N, --skip-numeric-underscore-normalization
>                                 Don't normalize underscores in numeric literals.

In VS Code, just add the following option in your User Settings JSON file:

```json
"python.formatting.blackArgs": ["--skip-numeric-underscore-normalization"]
```

Answer (score 5):

To avoid formatting literals, use `black --skip-numeric-underscore-normalization` or the short flag, `black -N`

You can make this a permanent change by modifying your pyproject.toml file:

```
[tool.black]
skip-numeric-underscore-normalization = true
```

https://github.com/ambv/black#189b0